# Cannot access machine after creating trough ec2 module within same script

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have problems with my playbook which should create new EC2 instances trough built-in module and connect to them to set some default stuff.

I went trough lot of tutorials/posts, but none of them mentioned same problem, therefor i'm asking there.

Everything, in terms of creating goes well, but when i have instances created, and successfully waited for SSH to come up. I got error which says machine is unreachable.

```
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ERROR! SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true}
```

I tried to connect manually (from terminal to the same host) and i was successful (while the playbook was waiting for connection). I also tried to increase timeout generally in ansible.cfg. I verified that given hostname is valid (and it is) and also tried public ip instead of public DNS, but nothing helps.

basically my playbook looks like that

```
---
  - name: create ec2 instances
    hosts: local
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    vars:
      machines:
         - { type: "t2.micro", instance_tags: { Name: "machine1", group: "some_group" }, security_group: ["SSH"] }
    tasks:
      - name: lunch new ec2 instances
        local_action: ec2
                      group={{ item.security_group }}
                      instance_type={{ item.type}}
                      image=...
                      wait=true
                      region=...
                      keypair=...
                      count=1
                      instance_tags=...
        with_items: machines
        register: ec2

      - name: wait for SSH to come up
        local_action: wait_for host={{ item.instances.0.public_dns_name }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
        with_items: ec2.results

      - name: add host into launched group
        add_host: name={{ item.instances.0.public_ip }} group=launched
        with_items: ec2.results

  - name: with the newly provisioned EC2 node configure basic stuff
    hosts: launched
    sudo: yes
    remote_user: ubuntu
    gather_facts: True
    roles:
      - common
```

Note: in many tutorials are results from creating ec2 instances accessed in different way, but thats probably for different question.

Thanks

**Solved:**

I don't know how, but it suddenly started to work. No clue. In case i will find some new info, will update this question

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error? Which play?

Comment: Its first task in common role (set_hostname). Basically when I'm trying access new machine for first time. Separation into two playbooks (which have to be runed separately) works, but i don't like it

Answer (score 1):

A couple points that may help:

1. I'm guessing it's a version difference, but I've never seen a 'results' key in the registered 'ec2' variable. In any case, I usually use 'tagged_instances' -- this ensures that even if the play didn't create an instance (ie, because a matching instance already existed from a previous run-through), the variable will still return instance data you can use to add a new host to inventory.
2. Try adding 'search_regex: "OpenSSH"' to your 'wait_for' play to ensure that it's not trying to run before the SSH daemon is completely up.

The modified plays would look like this:

```
- name: wait for SSH to come up
  local_action: wait_for host={{ item.public_dns_name }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started search_regex="OpenSSH"
  with_items: ec2.tagged_instances
- name: add host into launched group
  add_host: name={{ item.public_ip }} group=launched
  with_items: ec2.tagged_instances
```

You also, of course, want to make sure that Ansible knows to use the specified key when SSH'ing to the remote host either by adding 'ansible_ssh_private_key_file' to the inventory entry or specifying '--private-key=...' on the command line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestions.

ad 1) i know, its weird, i had to use debug many times to get it. i don't like it, but anyway

ad 2) thanks, will check a modify